# Why won't my controller connect?

Tags: ps3, controllers

My controller is an afterglow controller, and my tv is saying "connect controller using a usb cable and press the ps button" well my controller is on, the controllers usb drive or whatever it is, is in the play station and there is no way for my controller to be connected to the playstation other than that small usb drive thing, i dont know what to do..(ps3)

Comment: Try pressing the round button right in the middle of the controller while it's connected to the PlayStation 3.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the PlayStation 3 off, plug in the USB, then place the chip in the PlayStation 3. Now turn the system and the controller on, and let it connect the controller to the PlayStation. If this does not work, here are some things that might be the problem:

1. Dust can get in you PS3 outlets, take something and clean them or blow the dust out.
2. It might be the USB cable, get a new one.
3. Make sure you controller is not broken.
4. Your USB outlets might be bent, look and see.
5. Make sure the chip is in and the USB cable and plug the USB cable in your controller.

If this does not help,  maybe try the manual for the remote or PS3.

Comment: I forgot to add something look at @Ross Ridge post.

Comment: Also Anthony if this helped Upvote my answer and flag it as helpful so people can see this and let this help them out. It saves a lot of time.